# Distance fading for whole object

Tags: materials, shaders

i have created a dithered and stepped distance fading effect similar to lod transitions in video games.
the parameter is controlled by the camera's texture coordinates. (basically a gradient attached to camera)
this unfortunately results in vertices closer to the camera fading in first. see image:
[image: fading issue]
is there any way to keep this "distance to camera" value consistent for the entire object?
like calculate the distance of the object's origin from the camera?
or sample the current texture coordinate system form one vertex for the entire object?

one solution would be to use drivers. see image:
[image: driver solution]
the issue with this is that drivers don't change for object instances, like geometry nodes scattering.
any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated

#### SOLUTION

the second answer in the linked duplicate question, camera x, y and z position are added with a driver since there is only one camera.

Comment: it unfortunately doesn't, both answers affect the vertices of the object individually and not object as a whole.